# How to merge Trees together where the root of one tree equals the root of a other tree?

Tags: java, tree

I am currently trying to implement a tree(not binary, order doesn't matter , not-directed) data structure.
I want to merge Trees together when one Tree's root is the same as a children node of a other Tree.
Than the children of first tree should become children of the second tree children which is the same as the root of the first tree.
The trees to be merged could be deeper.

For example(The numbers are the identifier/Names of the vertices):
[image]

I implemented the `TreeNode.java` like this:

```
public class TreeNode {
    private TreeNode parent;
    private List<TreeNode> children;
    private IP vertexName;
    private int height;
    
    //This creates the root vertex, of the Tree.
    public TreeNode(IP vertexName) {
        this.vertexName = vertexName;
        this.parent = null;
        this.height = 0;
        this.children = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    //This is for creating other members of a tree besides the root, the children vertices.
    public TreeNode(TreeNode parentTreeNode, IP vertexName) {
        this.children = new ArrayList<>();
        this.parent = parentTreeNode;
        this.height = (parentTreeNode.getHeight() + 1);
        this.vertexName = vertexName;
        parentTreeNode.children.add(this);
    }


    public void addChildren(List<IP> verteciesIPs) throws NotATreeException {
        areValidChildren(verteciesIPs);

        for (IP ip:verteciesIPs) {
            TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode(ip);
            treeNode.setParent(this);
            treeNode.setHeight(this.getHeight() + 1);
            this.children.add(treeNode);
        }
    }

    public void addChild(TreeNode treeNodeChildren) {
        treeNodeChildren.setParent(this);
        treeNodeChildren.setHeight(this.getHeight() + 1);
        this.children.add(treeNodeChildren);
    }

    public void areValidChildren(final List<IP> verteciesIPs) throws NotATreeException {
        if (hasDuplicateChildren(verteciesIPs)) {
            throw new NotATreeException("Duplicate entries");
        }
```

I then have a list of trees `List<TreeNode> treeTopology` I want to merge together.
But I am not quite sure how to do that since I not only need to check if the children node are the same as the root node of a given Tree.
But also the children childrens and so on.

I hope somebody can help me with that.

I didn't post the whole code for simplification sake.

I tried iterating over the `List<TreeNode> treeTopology` with two `for-loops` and another `for-loop` for the children. But that approach doesn't seem to work very well. Because I can only compare the children and would need one more for loop for every children's children.

Comment: I think there needs to be more information. Are the values unique over all trees, or could for example 39 be the root of Tree2, Tree14, and Tree99?

Comment: Also, does the order in treeTopology play a role? Meaning can the tree at index 1 be 'added' to tree at index 0 but not to tree at index 2?

Comment: the roots of the tree should be unique.

Comment: and the order doesnt play a role

Comment: What do you do if Tree2 and Tree3 both have the same value at the root node? Take the first tree and drop the second, merge the children, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably implement a function to just check if the tree `contains()` a given number, then you could just call that function every time you want to add a new value. `if` tree `contains()` number `continue` else add number as child of the node to add to. You could try looking into DFS or BFS, since your tree resembles a graph more than an actual tree.